# Update mobile app when user delete data from website - Xamarin forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Problem:** Our mobile App users can update data from the website as well. All i want is to send a message to App (Android & iOS) to update user data as soon as user for example delete anything from website. What is the best way to achieve this?

**Environment:** Both Mobile App & Website is hosted by us. Website is built in Asp.net and Mobile App is done using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: SignalR was made to do this

Comment: Thanks. Don't have any experience whatsoever with SignalR. Did some research and looks like its more for the web based notification. Would it help to send silent message to a specific app and user?

Comment: https://montemagno.com/real-time-communication-for-mobile-with-signalr/